# Add active link class to current pathname with pagination

Tags: jquery

I currently have the following function in order to add the active link class to the navigation path

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    var navigation = $('#navigation');
    navigation.find('a[href="' + pathname + '"]').addClass("active-link");
    });
```

The problem happens when I go to a paginatied url.

For example this works when it is `domain.com/`, but when it is `domain.com/1` it does not.  I know find finds the exact, is there a way to do this if it contains at least the pathname?

Comment: Please add your html code for the navigation

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Rereading your post, I think I might have misunderstood... If you just want to match any link where the `href` attribute starts with a certain path, look at the [attribute prefix selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/). My original answer below might still be useful if your prefix path can contain slashes, so I'll leave it.

---

The problem is the presence of `/`in a jQuery selector. To quote the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

So if you need to use url paths in your jQuery selectors, you can do a simple `path.replace(/\//g, "\\\\/")` or write a more intelligent function that handles some of the other special characters as well.